# Find the degree of $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2, \sqrt7)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Set $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2, \sqrt7)$.

I can construct a basis for this extension as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ like this:

$\{1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{7}, \sqrt{14} \}$.

So I expect the degree to be 4, but here's my issue.  I cannot find a minimal polynomial of degree 4 that is irreducible.  Here is what I was able to find:

$\sqrt2$ has a minimal irreducible polynomial of $x^2 - 2$ and $\sqrt{7}$ has a minimal irreducible polynomial of $x^2 - 7$.  However, their product $x^4 - 9x + 14$ is not irreducible.  What am I missing?  How can I find the proper polynomial?

Comment: Helps to guess at a generator.  Hint:  try $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 7$.

Comment: Would it be $x^4 - 18x^2 +25$?

Comment: That looks good.

Comment: Note;  you still have to demonstrate that $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2 +\sqrt 7)$.  Not terribly difficult, but still.

Comment: +lulu, this would basically mean showing that the span of my basis is equal to the span of $\{\sqrt2 + \sqrt7, -\sqrt2 + \sqrt7, -\sqrt2 - \sqrt7, \sqrt2 - \sqrt7 \}$ correct?

Comment: Well, given that my field sits inside yours (so one direction is clear) I'd have said it was more natural to prove that bot $\sqrt 2,\sqrt 7$ sit inside the field generated by $\sqrt 2 +\sqrt 7$.  Again, this isn't terribly difficult but it is worth doing.

Comment: Okay, got it.  Also, the Galois group of this extension should just be the subset of $S_4$ that consists of the transpositions, correct?

Comment: Well, the full symmetric group is generated by the transpositions so I'm not sure where you are going with that.  Certainly the symmetric group is isomorphic to the Klein group of order $4$.

Comment: You don't need an explicit basis or a minimal polynomial of a (single) generator. You only need to figure out whether or not $\sqrt{7}\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$.